# why is clojure parallel deprecated

Tags: clojure, deprecated

I just found out about an old part of Clojure: `clojure.parallel`

http://clojure.org/reference/other_libraries#_parallel_processing_deprecated

Out of curiosity, why has it been deprecated?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if Clojure is fully capable of parallelizing on it's own without direct indications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-216 the reason is, that it would not work anymore with Java 7.